# Resend Confirmation Email if not sent to customers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I have the code that is sending confirmation email to customers on new account registration. I want the button on my page that customers can use to resend email confirmation link to their email if email previously not received by them

Not tried yet I'm new to .NET MVC, it's NopCommerce based.

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {

        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        string text = message.Body;
        string html = message.Body;
        //do whatever you want to the message        
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress("support@easypostagelabels.com");
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
        msg.Subject = message.Subject;
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(text, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("easypostagelabels.com", 25);// Convert.ToInt32(25));//587
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("support@easypostagelabels.com", "Admin@1234");
        smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
        try
        {

            smtpClient.Send(msg);
            string texterr = "success";
            // WriteAllText creates a file, writes the specified string to the file,
            // and then closes the file.    You do NOT need to call Flush() or Close().
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Content/error.txt"), texterr);
        }
        catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException E)
        {
            string texterr = E.Message;
            // WriteAllText creates a file, writes the specified string to the file,
            // and then closes the file.    You do NOT need to call Flush() or Close().
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Content/error.txt"), texterr);
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

guide me about code that customers use to resend email confirmation link

Comment: You say you haven't tried yet, well maybe you should try and see how it works?

Comment: It seems that you just need to look at the code that actually calls this method and place it in your button action.

Comment: If your "happy path" involves calling a method like this: `SendRegistrationConfirmationEmail(int userId)` or something to that effect, then the problem becomes simpler because resending mostly means just calling that method again. Getting to that point might involve some refactoring. Then that new method might create an `IdentityMessage` and call the method you've already written.